# I have two list and I want to create a dictionary from it . But I want to store multiple values for one key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I have two list as below

```
idx = [344, 344, 590]
newx = [(257, 381), (260, 368), (514, 245)]
```

I used the below code to make dictionary but it neglected one value . I want to store multiple values with one key.

```
res = dict(zip(idx, newx))
print(res)
```

output looks like `{344: (260, 368), 590: (514, 245)}` but I want output to be `{344: [(257, 381),(260, 368)], 590: [(514, 245)]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a defaultdict:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

idx = [344, 344, 590]
newx = [(257, 381), (260, 368), (514, 245)]

# default to empty list
res = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(idx, newx):
    res[k].append(v)

# get rid of default value
res = dict(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that as `dict` objects have unique keys. You should just the use list of tuple:

```
idx = [344, 344, 590]
newx = [(257, 381), (260, 368), (514, 245)]

res = zip(idx, newx)
print(list(res))
```

If you want to access all the values based on the key, use `collections.defaultdict`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want. Bonus, this won't require an import.

I hope this helps.

```py
res = {}
for k, v in zip(idx, newx):
    if k in res:
        res[k].append(v)
    else:
        res[k] = [v]
```